# Implementing Index trait for any type that implement my trait

Tags: rust

Is there any way to bypass rust orphan rule here? (i want to implement `Index` trait for any types that implement `Board` trait).

I mean, `Board` trait is mine, `CellLocation` struct is mine, `Piece` trait is mine, and indexing could be done by using `get_piece` for any struct that implements `Board`.

Or it's not idiomatic because user may want to implement his own indexing logic for his struct even if his struct implements `Board`? Or for any other reason?

```rust
pub trait Board {
    type Piece: Piece;

    fn get_piece(&self, location: CellLocation) -> Option<Self::Piece>;
}

// getting error here
impl<TBoard: Board> Index<CellLocation> for TBoard {
    type Output = TBoard::Piece;

    fn index(&self, index: CellLocation) -> &Self::Output {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

```rust
   |
56 | impl<TBoard: Board> Index<CellLocation> for TBoard {
   |      ^^^^^^ type parameter `TBoard` must be covered by another type when it appears before the first local type (`CellLocation`)
   |
   = note: implementing a foreign trait is only possible if at least one of the types for which it is implemented is local, and no uncovered type parameters appear before that first local type
   = note: in this case, 'before' refers to the following order: `impl<..> ForeignTrait<T1, ..., Tn> for T0`, where `T0` is the first and `Tn` is the last
```

Comment: There's nothing stopping a different crate from implementing both your `Board` trait and `Index<CellLocation>` separately, in which case there'd be two conflicting implementations of `Index<CellLocation>`. Avoiding the possibility of these scenarios is exactly why the orphan rule exists.

Comment: @Frxstrem so, just to avoid trait implementation conflicts? Okay, that make sence. I would have marked this as an answer, but I guess SO doesn't count comments as answers).